# Not able to disable Required Field Validator in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a required field validator for a textbox which I want to disable on click of a link button. I coded like so.

```
Protected Sub lnkDeleteTimeSlots_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    txtTimeslotName_RequiredFieldValidator.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

The design of the textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTimeslotName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<font color="red">*</font>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="txtTimeslotName_RequiredFieldValidator"
                            runat="server"
                            ErrorMessage="Timeslot Name Required!"
                            Display="None"
                            ControlToValidate="txtTimeslotName"
                            ForeColor="Red"
                            ValidationGroup="Timetable"> 
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

But it still validates for the required field. What is the issue?

**EDIT:**

The linkbutton is inside a grid. When it is clicked, I open a popup window with the textbox and a button. The code for the button is like so.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnMAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Timeslot" PostBackUrl="~/TimeSlots.aspx" OnClick="btnMAdd_Click" CssClass="button" ValidationGroup="Timetable"  OnClientClick="javascript:shouldsubmit=true;" />
```

Comment: How are you attaching this to your textbox?

Comment: On click of the linkbutton, a popup opens. The textbox is in the popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue - removed the **CausesValidation** from the linkbutton.

Answer (score 1):

Set `Cause Vlaidation` Property of Link Button to `false`like this...
CausesValidation="false"  so it will allow you to  call your code and disable your Validator...

Comment: @Aishvarya set the texbox validation group to `Timetable` too and make sure the valdaition group belong to controls inside modal popup

Comment: where is link button that disable the validator....you have anything else than textbox in your modal popup